# 404 error on all pages but custom post types are working OK

Tags: permalinks

I am getting 404 errors on all pages however I have multiple custom post types et up and these are working correctly.  I have tried all the usual fixes like htaccess file, flushing the rewrite links but to no avail.  I seem to be able to get pages working but have broken custom types or custom types working but no pages.  Any ideas gratefully accepted!

Comment: What's your permalink structure? What are the rewrite rules for your custom post types? Most likely, the issue is with one or the other. You can probably solve this by using [this plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) or [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/) to inspect your rewrite rules.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're using "pretty permalinks" with `%postname%`. If so, you need to make sure that you don't have page names that match your post type names. WordPress can only allow a particular slug to resolve to one page (that's why you can only get one or the other to work at a time). Or if you do have matching names, make sure when you register your post types that `has_archive` is set to `false` (disallows post type archives) or is set to a different slug (to avoid conflicts). Also, check your `rewrite` rules when registering your post types. For example, you might have something like:

```
'rewrite'   => array( 'slug' => 'news', 'with_front' => false ),
```

which means that your "news" post type will be first up in the permalink structure, whereas `with_front` set to `true` would prepend your existing permalink structure to the "news" slug. Read more about all this [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments).

The other possibility (without knowing more about your situation) is that you've recently moved your site. In which case you might need to "relocate" your site. See [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL#Relocate_method).

Hope something there is helpful. I know how frustrating those 404's can be...